# How to access WCF using TLS1.2 from UWP or windows8.1

Tags: wpf, wcf, uwp, windows-8.1, tls1.2

I'm using NetHttpBinding and ChannelFactory to access service, however not able to set secure protocol TLS1.2

`System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12`  will not work

`loadbalancer` upgraded to `TLS1.2` and my Windows 8.1 app failing.

```
            NetHttpBinding binding = new NetHttpBinding();

            // enable transport security on the binding for SSL connections
            if (connectionDetails.Secure)
            {
                binding.Security.Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport;
                binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.None;
            }

            EndpointAddress endpoint = new EndpointAddress(endpointUri.ToString());

            _factory = new ChannelFactory<IDataService>(binding, endpoint);
            _channel = _factory.CreateChannel();
```

Comment: I notice you choose the wpf,uwp and windows-8.1 labels, so can you tell us if you write the same code in them and they all fail after setting TLS1.2?

Comment: I found UWP app by default using TLS1.2 to access WCF.

Comment: So do you have any other question for this?